Surfing social media is one of the most, if not the most popular ______ among my friends => pastime or pastimes?

Surfing social media is one of the most, if not the most popular ______ among my friends.


Should I use "pastime" or "pastimes" here?
Should I place a comma between "most" and "popular"? If I should, the answer is "pastimes", isn't it?


You could always rearrange or reword the sentence to avoid the matter. As an example, Surfing social media is perhaps the most popular pastimes among my friends means nearly the same because if the activity could be the most popular, then it’s unlikely that it’s not near the top in popularity.

No plural without one of the most popular of pastimes.

It's the plural one.  The parenthetical is just an "add on". The sentence has to work without the parenthetical.

@PaulTanenbaum's suggestion is good but I think you meant to use the singular.

I think this sentence is a good example of ones that make a lot of native speakers stop and wonder what's right.

Yes, @Lambie and AndyBonner are right. Sadly, by the time I saw the comment my 5-minute edit window had shut.

@PaulTanenbaum Just so you know, when this happens to me, I copy my original comment, make corrections and repost. This sharing what I do.

Surfing social media is one of the most, if not the most, popular pastimes among my friends.
This is the most natural way to express it in English.


Surfing social media is one of the most, if not the most popular ______ among my friends.

Bracketing commas come in pairs, and hence we need a second one.  However, this can't work.  The sentence is problematic as
one of the most needs a plural, but
the most needs a singular.
I suggest this slight re-ordering:

Surfing social media as a pastime is one of the most, if not the most, popular among my friends.


I think you ignore the parenthetical when determining the pluralization. It may sound weird because "the most" is closer to the noun.

Popular what? You've broken the sentence up in a way that doesn't work in English.

Putting "pastime" in front just makes the sentence more awkward. To be valid, you need another pair of commas: "Surfing social media, as a pastime, is...," to keep us from parsing "surfing social media as a pastime" as a single phrase (like "doing X for work"). At that point, the levels of inverted syntax seem odd, like saying "This truck, as a vehicle, is the reddest in the parking lot" instead of "this truck is the reddest vehicle in the parking lot."

Sorry - as a native English speaker, your suggested re-ordering doesn't sound natural to me.
